# how to get a div values and split it to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

there is a div with some values like this:

```
<div id="links">
<link1>||<link2>||<link3>
</div>
```

i know in javascript we can make an array of a string with `str.split("||");` but my problem is i can't define a variable for some reasons in this case, i just need to get values of div block like a var,but i don't know how, i need something like this from above block:

```
var str = '<link1>||<link2>||<link3>';
```

Comment: Do you want a string or array of strings?

Comment: first i need a string then i need to make an array of it! so finally i need array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML) from your div and then trim it by removing spaces at the begining and end of your string:

```
var str = document.getElementById('links').innerHTML.
            replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');
```

Then you can go ahead and do:

```
var arr = str.split("||");
```

Comment: thanks a lot all gays, it worked! but also i need to delete last || because my links come from a weblog system and this link system is auto, links are like this: `link1||link2||link3||` please help me to solve this problem too. thank you again

Comment: @Vahid You can strip off the last `||` at the same time as the trailing spaces just by changing `/\s*$/` to `/\|\|\s*$/` :)

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
var array = document.getElementById('links').innerHTML.trim().split('||');
```

If you only want a string, use this:

```
var str = document.getElementById('links').innerHTML.trim();
```

Comment: +1 - This is the same as my answer with the difference that it will be slightly faster on browsers that support `trim` but won't work on non-modern browsers without a shim.

Comment: What browsers do not support it?

Comment: Almost any browser that wasn't released in the last couple of years. The most popular browser that doesn't support it is probably `IE 8`.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I was thinking 'innerHTML', but never typed it. :P